# How to add composite primary key using fluent API in ef core?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I want to add composite primary key using fluent API in entity framework core.

My database context looks like this, where PropertyId & ImageId are foreign keys.

```
builder.Entity<PropertyImage>().HasKey(x => new { x.PropertyId, x.ImageId });
```

When I do the migration, it does create two foreign keys and they make composite primary key but I want to have 2 rows with same PropertyId with different ImageId, it gives me the following error as shown in an image below. How do I achieve this?
[image: Database rows in SSMS]